# Show that a simple graph G, where the degree of all vertices are at least half of G's order, has a hamiltonian cycle

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonicity

Consider a  graph G on n vertices (n != 2) , where the degree of any given vertex is at least n/2. I am trying to prove it has a hamiltonian cycle.
I tried proving that it has a spanning path, but then I noticed: it doesn't follow immediately from that fact that G has a spanning cycle, I also tried maximality arguments, but failed.

Comment: This follows from a theorem in Trudeau's Introduction to Graph Theory: [Ch 8 thm 72] "If the sum of the degrees of every pair of vertices of a graph $G$ is at least $v,$ then $G$ has a closed hamiltonian walk." [In Trudeau, $v$ is the number of vertices in graph $G.$]

Comment: This is known as [Dirac's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path#Bondy%E2%80%93Chv%C3%A1tal_theorem).

Comment: @coffeemath I mean, I'm sure Trudeau mentions it - because it's Ore's theorem (this question being Dirac's theorem) and practically every textbook mentions both - but Trudeau on Hamiltonian cycles specifically is a terrible source. The book claims that the reason the Hamiltonian cycle problem is hard is that it takes too long to compute the degree sums.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Not only mentioned, but there is a proof in Trudeau. [I recalled the theorem and that's the only source I had available.]

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3732299/proof-for-hamiltonian-graph-by-number-of-vertex and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731482/proving-that-a-graph-is-hamiltonian-ores-theorem and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814096/ores-theorem-graph-theory and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597503/prove-that-a-graph-with-p-vertices-and-2p-1p-2-2-edges-is-hamiltonian and many others.

Comment: Thank you so much!